# Can every natural number $8m - 3$ be written as either $o_c(n,x)$ or $o_d(n,x)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have the following two formulas, which for $n > 1$, $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x \in \Bbb N$ lead to linear equations of the type $o(n) = mx + b$ if only n is set and to certain odd numbers if both are set ($o(n,x)$):

1. $$o_c(n,x) = 2^{2n}x - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{2i-1} - 1$$
2. $$o_d(n,x) = 2^{2n+1}(x - 1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2^{2i} + 1$$

My problem is the following:

Can every natural number $8m−3, m \in \Bbb N$ be written as either $o_c(n,x)$ or $o_d(n,x)$ for suitable $n,x$?

For instance, $5$ can be written as $o_d(2,1)$, $13$ can be written as $o_c(2,1)$, $21$ can be written as $o_c(3,1)$.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to prove it myself and would really appreciate some help. Can someone please help me out on this?

[IMPORTANT EDIT] Here something that would really help me to solve this based on these examples:

- Set $n = 2$ for $o_c$: $o_c(2,x) = 16x - 3$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $16x - 11$.
- Set $n = 2$ for $o_d$: $o_d(2,x) = 32x - 27$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $32x - 11$.
- Set $n = 3$ for $o_c$: $o_c(3,x) = 64x - 11$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $64x - 43$.
- Set $n = 3$ for $o_d$: $o_d(3,x) = 128x - 107$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $128x - 43$.
- Set $n = 3$ for $o_c$: $o_c(4,x) = 256x - 43$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $256x - 171$.
- Set $n = 3$ for $o_d$: $o_d(4,x) = 512x - 427$. The numbers remaining to be proven is $512x - 171$.
- ...

One can see that only one half of the previously to be proven numbers remains.

Prove that the remaining numbers to be proven can be written as either:

1. $$r_Oc(n,x) = 2^{2n}x - \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i$$ if $o_c$ is used to show that the next half of the previously remaining numbers belongs to the numbers proven now, or
2. $$r_Oc(n,x) = 2^{2n-1}x - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$$ if $o_d$ is used to show that the next half of the previously remaining numbers belongs to the numbers proven now.

If this were proven I would be able to solve it.

Comment: This is hard to follow.   What's the connection between the first two formulas?  What is $y$?  What on earth does the question in the header mean?

Comment: @lulu $y$ stands for the linear equations resulting from the two formulas for n equals 1, 2, 3, ... There is no question in the header but it means (if you’ve read the entire question) “prove that A is a subset of B”.

Comment: $y$ is an equation?  What equation is it?  Really, this question makes no sense.  I couldn't get through the first couple of lines.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: I’ve edited it, please don’t close it... I still have to learn a lot but I’m trying my best. Please bear with me @lulu

Comment: Ok, I retracted my close vote.  I think, but am not sure, that all you are asking is "can every odd natural number be written as $o_c(n,x)$ or $o_d(n,x)$ for suitable $n,x$?"  Is this accurate?

Comment: @lulu Exactly, this is what my question boils down to

Comment: I would write it that way then.  How do you write $1$ in the desired form?

Comment: This is the thing: If the upper limit of the sum is $0$ (due to $1-1$ for $o_d(1)$) it doesn’t work. The sum should be excluded if and only if the upper limit is zero (which only is the case for $n = 1$. If it were, formula 2 would lead to $8x - 7$ ($x = 1$ leads to $o_d(1,1) = 1$ @lulu

Comment: Didn't follow that.  Can $1$ be written as $o_c(n,x)$ or $o_d(n,x)$?  If so, just write it down.  If not...well, that settles the question, no?

Comment: @lulu I will edit it later again, because I currently only have my phone with me. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: If you want a fancier approach, I think (but haven't checked) that $\sum \frac 1n$ converges if you restrict the sum to those $n$ which can be written the way you like.  If true, that would show that infinitely many $n$ can not be so expressed.

Comment: @lulu Not really, the $n=1$ cases were supposed to belong to the different sets... I’ll state it this way: “Can every natural number $8z - 3$ be written as $o_c(n,x)$ or $o_d(n,x)$ for suitable $n,x$?”

Comment: Please edit the question to ask a single, clear question.  If I am correct about the convergence, that would settle your refined question as well.  ?

Comment: @lulu ok, I’ll try right now

Comment: For the refined question, regarding $8x-3$, write out the first few candidates in detail.  How do you write $5, 13, 21, 29,\cdots$?

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the tip! It should be much clearer and much more straightforward now...

Comment: No problem. I did a quick search and, despite what I said earlier, it looks like we get all modest sized numbers of the form $8k-3$  I wasn't terribly  systematic but I believe I checked at least the first few hundred values.

Comment: @lulu sounds awesome! Do you already have ideas on how one could approach it?

Comment: I would work inductively.  Try to construct the representation of the next one given that you'd done all those prior.

Comment: That’s where I start struggling: What would be my assumption after showing that it works for one m, x and n? The first step seems so unclear to me... @lulu

Comment: I don't see a good line of attack immediately.  One thought:  Maybe you can use the binary expansion of $8k-3$ to see how to construct a representation.

Comment: @lulu I've edited something that would give me a decisive help. If this could be proven I would be able to solve it.

Comment: I'll post if I have something to contribute.  For now, I'd say the idea was to look at the sequences $\{o_c(n,1)\}=13,53,213,\cdots$ and $\{o_d(n,1)\}=5,21,85,\cdots\}$ and argue that every number of the form $8k-3$ is congruent to one of these modulo an appropriate power of $2$.  But I might well have it wrong.